# Not allowed to load local resource Problem

Tags: html, next.js13

I've encountered a "Not allowed to load local resource" error in my Next.js application. My app exports files from Confluence and saves them locally. However, when opening various pages, some photos fail to load with this error. I'm certain the photos exist as they can be easily opened through a standard photo editor or directly in the browser via their paths.

```
file:///Y:/ukt/man/manual_sa_ru/public/content/121733128/file4.png
```

In the network, requests to these files are marked as "blocked: other". Meanwhile, other photos load without any issues, as if randomly some images fail to load despite all of them having the same PNG extension and standardized naming conventions.

I'm really asking for someone to help me because I don't even understand where to start checking. Disabling the browser's security systems also led to no results.